# How to use regular expression to get the number of matches in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I started learning regular expression recently. I have a small problem statement now.

I am having a pattern like this

```
var pattern = /^(?:hawaian(?:beach|pizza|hotel))$/gim;
var text = "hawaian hotel is near hawaian beach. In the hawaian hotel they sell hawaian pizza";
```

I want to actually match hawaian hotel, hawaian beach and hawaian pizza in this text.

But the pattern is returning true only for conditions like hawaianhotel || hawaianbeach || hawaianpizza.

So i tried like this

```
 var text = "hawaianhotel is near hawaianbeach. In the hawaianhotel they sell hawaianpizza";
```

But this is also not working.

Only this one is working

```
var matches = pattern.exec('hawaian*');
```

Comment: On problem in your first expression is that there is no space between `hawaian` and the other words. It could never match `hawaian beach`. Another problem is that you are anchoring the expression at the beginning *and* end of the string, but your string contains many more characters than just `hawaianhotel` or `hawaianbeach`.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good place to learn more about regular expressions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern uses beginning and end of string anchors, so you would only match strings if the pattern matches the entire string.  Remove the `^` and `$` and you should be okay.  Note that I also added a space so that you can match "hawaian hotel" instead of "hawaianhotel".

```
var pattern = /(?:hawaian (?:beach|pizza|hotel))/gim;
```

Comment: Thank you..I understood more on regexp from your answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
(?:hawaiian[ ](?:beach|pizza|hotel))
```

this will match on hawaiian pizza

Notice the [ ] if for example you wanted to match hawaiian2hotel you would do [0-9] or [2] or if you wanted to match "hawaiian          (arbitrary number of spaces)      hotel" you would do [ ]* (zero or more) or [ ]+ (one or more)

also, this is a wonderful tool
http://iblogbox.com/devtools/regexp/

Comment: You don't need the `[]`, you can just put a space there.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = /(?:hawaian[ ](?:beach|pizza|hotel))/gim;
```